# Android : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Some dex are not uncompressed and aligned correctly for <Application Id of app here>

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk, dex

I am trying to enable the embeddedDex attribute in AndroidManifest as part of increasing app and apk security for Android 10 and above, but when attempting to do so, I keep getting this INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK error as the apks attempt to install into my testing Android device and emulators.

I follow the steps outlined in [Run embedded dex code directly from APK](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/dex) and clean -> rebuild project and a sync with gradle, builds fine, but fails at apk installation.

Android Studio IDE was incredibly vague on this, showing only INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK with three extracted apks as shown when attempting to install on my physical Android test device:

```
[0] 'app/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/buildvariant/base-arm64_v8a.apk'
[1] 'app/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/buildvariant/base-mdpi.apk'
[2] 'app/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/buildvariant/base-master.apk'
The APKs are invalid.
```

Digging through the IDE's log file, I get the more clearer reasoning for failure:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Some dex are not uncompressed and aligned correctly for <Application Id of app here>
```

And this is where I'm not sure where my next steps are to continue and resolve this critical error.
Can anyone help me understand how to continue and address this issue?

Comment: Can you verify the DEX files are indeed stored compressed in APK files? Perhaps Android Studio doesn't properly customize the output APK files? Can you try to temporary increase the minSdkVersion to 29 and then retry?

Comment: Thanks. I tried up'ing the minSdkVersion from 26 to 29, but unfortunately that changed nothing from what I've seen. Still getting the INVALID_APK thrown on installation. 
I'm not sure how to validate if DEX files are still compressed after setting that useLegacyPackaging flag in packagingOptions under dex block in the app module's build.gradle, I didn't touch the application's build.gradle.
To add context, I have some external libraries added as .AAR files, but when I imported the same libraries in a fresh project with the same useEmbeddedDex attribute, it installed and ran fine.

Comment: The error message tells you to store the dex files in the APK without ZIP compressed (store algorithm) and furthermore apply zipalign tool before resigning the APK files.

Answer (score 1):

Occurred the same issue, when building signed apk with this attribute :
`android:useEmbeddedDex ="true"`
we figure out that's is reproducable only with signed bundle file "aab" not for APK file.

As workaround, i replaced this option of gradle :

```
packagingOptions {
    dex {
      useLegacyPackaging = false
    }
  }
```

by this option :

```
    aaptOptions{
        noCompress 'dex'
   }
```

Which works correctly neither APK of AAB generated signed file.

Btw, i have open a ticket for Google Team raising this issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/322755410